# From list of strings, create new list where each item indicates if corresponding item in original list is in between two specific entries

Tags: python

Say that I have this list

```
jay = ['Despite', 'similar', 'intensity', 'of', 'alcohol', '<Disease:D013375>', 'withdrawal', 'symptoms', '</Disease:D013375>', ',', 'ALC', '/', 'COC', 'subjects', 'received', 'less', 'oxazepam', 'to', 'treat', 'alcohol', '<Disease:D013375>', 'withdrawal', 'symptoms', '</Disease:D013375>', 'compared', 'to', 'ALC', 'subjects', '.']
```

I want to make a new list that corresponds to the original list. If an item is in between items `'<Disease:XXXXX>'` and `'</Disease:XXXXX>'`, the first item will get tagged with 'B-COL' , and rest will get tagged with 'I-COL'.

The items `'<Disease:XXXXX>'` and `'</Disease:XXXXX>'` themselves do not get any tags. The XXXX can range in number of digits.

All other items get tagged with 'O'.

So here is an example output I want.

```
idealOutput= ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-COL', 'I-COL', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-COL', 'I-COL', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

The number of pairs of 'Disease' tags can vary, as does the number of items in between those tags.

Here's my attempt at this:

```
wow = jay
labs = []
for i in range(0, len(wow)):
    if wow[i].startswith("<Disease"):
        labs.append('DelStrB')
    elif i>0 and i<=len(labs):
        if labs[i-1] == 'DelStrB':
            labs.append('B-COL')
            i = i + 1
            while not (wow[i].startswith("</Disease")):
                labs.append('I-COL')
                i = i + 1
            if wow[i].startswith("</Disease"):
                labs.append('DelStrE')
                i = i + 1
        elif wow[i].startswith("</Disease"):
            k=9 #do nothing
        else:
            labs.append('O')
    elif wow[i].startswith("</Disease"):
        k=9 #do nothing
    else:
        labs.append('O')

labs[:] = [x for x in labs if x != 'DelStrB']
labs[:] = [x for x in labs if x != 'DelStrE']

print(labs)
```

The result is

```
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-COL', 'I-COL', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-COL', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

Which is incorrect. I also know that there's a much more computationally efficient, and elegant way of coding this, but unable to produce it.

Comment: When you used a debugger to follow the execution, and you got to where it should have inserted the missing `I-COL`, why did it not insert it?

Comment: Using pdb? It doesn't seem to display this. Is there a different debugger or method you're thinking of?

Comment: It doesn't display what?  It will display anything you ask it to, when you ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple generator:

```
import re
jay = ['Despite', 'similar', 'intensity', 'of', 'alcohol', '<Disease:D013375>', 'withdrawal', 'symptoms', '</Disease:D013375>', ',', 'ALC', '/', 'COC', 'subjects', 'received', 'less', 'oxazepam', 'to', 'treat', 'alcohol', '<Disease:D013375>', 'withdrawal', 'symptoms', '</Disease:D013375>', 'compared', 'to', 'ALC', 'subjects', '.']
def results(d):
  _flag = -1
  for i in d:
    if re.findall('\<Disease:\w+\>', i):
      _flag = 1
    elif re.findall('\</Disease:\w+\>', i):
      _flag = -1
    else:
      if _flag == -1:
        yield 'O'
      elif _flag == 1:
        yield 'B-COL'
        _flag = 0
      else:
        yield 'I-COL'

print(list(results(jay)))
```

Output:

```
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-COL', 'I-COL', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-COL', 'I-COL', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that uses an iterative approach:

```
jay = ['Despite', 'similar', 'intensity', 'of', 'alcohol', '<Disease:D013375>', 'withdrawal', 'symptoms', '</Disease:D013375>', ',', 'ALC', '/', 'COC', 'subjects', 'received', 'less', 'oxazepam', 'to', 'treat', 'alcohol', '<Disease:D013375>', 'withdrawal', 'symptoms', '</Disease:D013375>', 'compared', 'to', 'ALC', 'subjects', '.']

result = []

inside = False
seen_BCOL = False

for i in range(len(jay)):
    if jay[i].startswith('<Disease'):
        inside = True
    elif jay[i].startswith('</Disease'):
        inside = False
        seen_BCOL = False
    elif inside == True:
        if seen_BCOL == False:
            result.append('B-COL')
            seen_BCOL = True
        else:
            result.append('I-COL')
    elif inside == False:
        result.append('O')


print(result)

['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B-COL', 'I-COL', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B-COL', 'I-COL', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with a key function that looks for the "Disease" items to separate the list into odd and even-numbered groups for different methods of tagging:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby
[t for i, l in enumerate(list(g) for k, g in groupby(jay, key=lambda s: re.match(r'</?Disease:\w+>', s)) if not k) for t in (('B-COL',) + ('I-COL',) * (len(l) - 1) if i % 2 else ('O',) * len(l))]
```

This returns:

```
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-COL', 'I-COL', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-COL', 'I-COL', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

Note that your expected output is incorrect because it has 2 more `'O'`s in between the two sequences of `'B-COL'` and `'I-COL'`s.